# Can Extended Events be used instead of Auditing?

Tags: sql-server, audit, extended-events

In [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#server-audit-specification) it is mentioned:

[image]

Does this mean Extended Events can capture all the events that are traced by auditing? Can we get all the functionalities of auditing just by using XEvents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Extended Events can capture all the events that are traced by auditing?

Yes and no. The built in auditing framework is built upon the extended events framework. This means any of the built in auditing will be serviced via the XE framework, assuming it is setup.

> Can we get all the functionalities of auditing just by using XEvents?

You can get most, but it's not 100% coverage. Since the auditing is built upon the framework there would be the possibility, however not all auditing events have a 1 to 1 or even a correlated mapping to non-auditing based extended events.

Comment: Also the auditing functionality has hooks in the engine to do things like preventing the service from running if the audit is not available to capture data.   And preventing the disabling of the audit functions while the service is running.